# What is appropriate for a Global field in terms of site speed?

Tags: globals

I'm worried that if I put too much in globals, I will impact the speed of my site by a lot.

For example, I was thinking of putting content in there like matrices for team members (text and image), testimonials, award's (text and images), etc.

Is this content better put somewhere else? I know globals are called on every single site load, so I'm not sure if having that type of content in there is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak on the speed impact of having lots of content in the Globals, but the use cases you have described don't really seem suitable for Globals.

I would instead recommend creating Sections for each of these (Testimonials, Awards, The Team) and have an entry for each item.

We use the Globals section (for example) for setting the clients phone number, contact address, email address etc. Just little pieces of information that can be re-used. Quite considerably different to the large content sections you have described.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, that sounds like a good idea. I suppose having a channel with no URLs would be appropriate here

Basic text fields for globals is what I'd like to keep it to.

Comment: Exactly that. It's important to remember that Entries don't always have to be accessible pages. You can have an entry called "Awards" that just loops through all entries in an Awards section, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jamie's answer re: how to build out a site's IA.

As for performance, each additional global set adds queries to every page that is loaded. It's pretty unlikely that there will be a huge performance impact unless you really go overboard, but it's important to keep in mind that every global set involves several queries that load in the data for every page request.